# Scala code works on Spark Terminal but not in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, scala, apache-spark

The code below works fine when I run it on Spark Terminal but in eclipse it throws an error. What might be the reason. Please let me know if you need more information.

**val IABLabels= IAB.zip(labels) 

val temp1 = IABLabels.groupBy(x=>x._2).mapValues( _.map( _._1 ))**

**Error in Eclipse:

value mapValues is not a member of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Int, Iterable[(String, Int)])]**

The code runs perfectly fine on Spark shell.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use this import to access extra functions on RDD's of (key,value) pairs through an implicit conversion:

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
```

You can check the [API](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/#org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions) docs for further details.

Comment: Thank you very much......that fixed it. I was importing org.apache.spark.SparkContext....after adding ._ the error is gone